# How to get Apple font rendering on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, mac, rendering, cleartype

No, I am not trying to start a flame war. :-)

I understand, that this is purely matter of taste. Both [Joel](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2007/06/12/font-smoothing-anti-aliasing-and-sub-pixel-rendering/) & [Jeff](https://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-apples-font-rendering/) have stated their opinions on the matter. I for one love the way the Mac displays fonts and whenever trying to read a longer text on my PC I get frustrated and employ a hack:

- print it into OneNote - apparently the act of printing it changes the algorithm used and the resulting picture has a much better look (makes kind of sense due to the different resolution).

What I really want is to have the Apple Font Rendering used everywhere in Windows. Currently I use the [ClearType Tuning PowerToy](https://web.archive.org/web/20130503062947/http://www.microsoft.com/typography/ClearTypePowerToy.mspx) to crank up the thickness of the font to the max, but I am not really satisfied. The above mentioned articles from Joel & Jeff explain why that is.

So basically I am looking for an alternative to ClearType. I do not mind spending money for it if it works. Any recommendations?

Comment: Answer 2: "GDI++ is rather old.. Mactype is much more better." Must be picked as an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anything (apart from GDI++) to improve font rendering on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/108312/anything-apart-from-gdi-to-improve-font-rendering-on-windows)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To achieve this you can use GDI++, which is an application that renders the fonts on Windows applications with GDI instead of the typical ClearType.

- [ZIP-file containing GDI++ only](http://drwatson.nobody.jp/gdi++/gdi++20060927.zip)
- [ZIP-file containing GDI++ (with trayicon)](http://vladg.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/gdi.zip)
- [RAR-file containing GDI++ (with trayicon, *newer*)](http://cid-07e7c6cfbcdf7bdc.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Public/Various/GDI++.rar)

**Usage without trayicon:**
   Just drag and drop your favourite application to  gdi++.exe.  Native Windows controls are also now in effect.

**Usage with trayicon:**
Just right-click the trayicon and select `Enable`.

Comment: Wow, I just tried it, and I think it's working. Text actually looks bearable! I had been quarantined to my MacBook for a while because it was a pain to read on my Computer. ClearType didn't seem to do much. I still have ClearType on in conjunction with this and it looks great. Going to keep running it for a while to see if I run into any issues. Thanks though.

Comment: Something I noticed in Visual Studio was that scrolling up and down lagged a bit, but I think this is a great little thing that I can choose to turn on when necessary, and I can live with a little bit of lag if it makes everything a whole lot more readable!

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: This approach is somewhat buggy with some applications and has problems with 64-bit Windows, but other than that it's very nice.

Answer (score 5):

GDI++ is rather old and not compatible with many software such as Google Chrome. It doesn't work on Windows 8 and above either. [Mactype](https://www.mactype.net/) is much more better and is [still in active development](https://github.com/snowie2000/mactype). It supports both GDI and DirectWrite apps and has many more tuning options to make the result suits you.

[image: mactype profile]

[image: mactype option]

> ## What's new?
>
> - Win10 compatible
> - Updated FreeType (up to git commit 0c4feb72cf976f63d4bf62436bc48f190d0e0c28)
> - Support for color fonts
> - New installer
> - Lots of bug fixes
> - Updates for multi-monitor support
> - Tray app can intercept explorer in Service Mode now
> - Tweaks for diacritics
> - Updates to EasyHook
> - Lower CPU in Tray Mode
> - Better DirectWrite support thanks to しらいと[http://silight.hatenablog.jp]
> - Separate DirectWrite parameter adjustment
> - Traditional Chinese localization greatly improved thanks to GT Wang
> - English localization improved
> - Added Korea localization, thanks to 조현희
> - MultiLang system improved
> - (Does not include Infinality as this is still experimental)

https://github.com/snowie2000/mactype

Comment: Current repo location for MacType is here: https://github.com/snowie2000/mactype