# Is it possible to get Safari / OS X style font rendering in Chrome or Firefox? How?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, fonts, safari

I prefer the OS X / Safari-on-Windows font rendering engine over Windows' ClearType, but I am not fond of Safari as a browser. Given that Chrome also uses Webkit, is it possible to enable/port the Safari text engine to it? What about Firefox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Apple font rendering on Windows (XP)?](http://superuser.com/questions/16734/how-to-get-apple-font-rendering-on-windows-xp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [gdipp](http://code.google.com/p/gdipp/) instead of GDI++ (also supports win7 x64 + 64 bit apps).

Comment: I recommend GDIPP too because GDI++ create some issues is some software that GDIPP doesn't. (VS2010, Office 2010...)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/16734/how-to-get-apple-font-rendering-on-windows-xp) which covers getting Apple-style font rendering throughout Windows.

The trick is to use [GDI++](http://lifehacker.com/5190607/gdi%252B%252B-adds-os-x-font-rendering-to-windows).

Comment: It's certainly different from the Windows font rendering but it's not exactly like the Apple style rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that before and it's pretty clunky. Besides, I only really want Safari rendering in-browser atm, rather that throughout the OS.